# Is it possible to re-assign an existing UITableView to a different UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Most of my app is created programmatically, but I have a handful of complex views that are created using Interface Builder and loaded programmatically.

In one view I have a UITableViewController subclass created programmatically, and its tableView property is assigned to the UITableView instance in the XIB, referenced as an IBOutlet.  This happens in the XIB's UIViewController's viewDidLoad, and the table view displays correctly.

At one point, I need to change the entire contents of the table view.  Ideally, I would like to disconnect that view from the first UITableViewController and connect it to a different one that will feed it different data.  Attempting to assign the view to the new controller's tableView property results in "A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!"  Assigning the previous controller's tableView to nil before assigning the new one avoids the error, but the table view disappears from the screen.

Honestly, I know the table view instance is usually managed by the UITableViewController.  I can't find anything in the docs about setTableView automatically setting the back references for delegate and dataSource in an assigned tableView, so I'm surprised my externally-created tableView works in the first place.  In fact, the TVC docs seem to discuss UITableViewController's tableView property as readonly, even though it is not tagged as such.

Comment: Did you also try adding the UITableView to the UITableViewController's view?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Do you mean assigning the UITableView as the TVC's view, or adding it as a subview?  TVC ideally doesn't have its own view as it should just be the assigned tableView.  I was not setting it explicitly as I assumed UITableViewController's default setTableView would set it for me.  Checking it while debugging seems to confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I don't have all your information, but on the surface it seems that you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Why don't you just use the current UITableViewController and corresponding UITableView and reload it with "new data". Alternatively, just programmatically create another UITableViewController and use that for your new data. Is there a compelling reason to recycle the UITableView?

Comment: The TVCs hold dissimilar types of data, with different cell types, source object classes, etc.  It's not simply a refresh or even a subset of the original data.  For sanity's sake, it makes sense that they are separate controllers.  You are right on your second point:  Due to the trouble, there is not a really compelling reason to reuse the view.  The setup of the container view was complex, but it would no doubt be easier and less complex to swap two separate TVC-managed UITableViews in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no**, and here's why:

I checked with the debugger, and the normal setTableView does set the view property on self as well as setting the delegate and dataSource properties on the new incoming tableView.  This is not documented by Apple, but it was the assumed behaviour and so it was all well and good.

What I did not realize is that the default setView (from UIViewController) will *remove an existing view from its superview* before setting the new one.  To prevent the "one view controller at a time" runtime error I was setting the old TVC's tableView to nil, which caused the tableView I intended to reuse to be removed from the view hierarchy.  To avoid this behaviour, one would have to override setView, which is more complicated than I care to get into for this task.

Reusing views (in this case, a UITableView instance) is not supported by Apple.  It is not mentioned in the UITableViewController documentation, but it is mentioned in the [UITableViewController documentation regarding the view property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW2).  Arguably, UITableViewController's tableView property should be marked *readonly* by Apple, with its tableView solely managed internally, but there's probably a good reason why its not.